# Error with global variables are not defined in a thread function on python

Tags: python, multithreading, global-variables, ocr, nameerror

I'm working in a project with OCR using a webcam. I defined a `capture()` function for save the **frame** that contains minimum 20 contours with areas greater than 60 pixels in lapses of 3 seconds. I need that the main while cycle works all the time. So I'm using a thread to call `capture()` function. When I run the code the Python Shell returned an error: *NameError: global name frame, ln2 are not defined*. The 13th commented line solves the error for the variable *frame*. Does it means that I have to replicate all the code that is inside the while cycle?

I'm using python 2.7 on Windows 7.

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import time
import threading

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def capture():
    global frame, ln2
    if ln2 > 20:
        cv2.imwrite("frame.jpg", frame)
        time.sleep(3)

#ret, frame = cap.read() #it solves the error for variable 'frame'

child_t = threading.Thread(target = capture)
child_t.setDaemon(True)
child_t.start()

while(1):
    a = []
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    img1 = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _, img2 = cv2.threshold(img1, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    (_, contornos, _) = cv2.findContours(img2, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    ln = len(contornos)

    for i in range (0, ln):
        cn = contornos[i]
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cn)
        area = 2*(w+h)

        if area > 60 and area < 1000:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            a.append(area)

    ln2 = len(a)
    print ln2

    #here I want to call capture() function

    cv2.imshow('Webcam', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('x'):
        break

child_t.join()

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I'm still at my first coffee today, but i don't see you declaring the globals in the top scope. Only in the function. You need to do it outside the function as well. In bytecode, if you want to dis it, it would show as STORE_GLOBAL and in your function it's LOAD_GLOBAL. No STORE and LOAD fails, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. Note that I'm using `threading.Timer` instead of `threading.Thread` followed by a `time.sleep`.

Also, You said you need to *save the frame that contains minimum 20 contours with areas greater than 60 pixels*, but the related `if` statement in your code doesn't do that. So I've added that as well.

The message *NameError: global name frame, ln2 are not defined* is because the thread is started even before `frame` is being read. Same applies to the variable `ln2` as well. This is also fixed in the code below. Basically I used the flag `writeToFile` to overcome this issue.

```
import threading
import cv2

writeToFile = False
exitTask = False

def threadTask():
    global frame
    if not exitTask:
        threading.Timer(3.0, threadTask).start()
        if writeToFile:
            cv2.imwrite("Threads.jpg", frame)
            print "Wrote to file"


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
threadTask()

while(True):
    areasList = []

    try:
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        img1 = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        _, img2 = cv2.threshold(img1, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        (_, contours, _) = cv2.findContours(img2, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        nContours = len(contours)

        for contour in contours:
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            area = 2*(w+h)

            #if area > 60 and area < 1000:
            if (nContours > 10) and (area > 20):
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                areasList.append(area)
                writeToFile = True
            else:
                writeToFile = False

        #print len(areasList)

        cv2.imshow('Webcam', frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('x'):
            raise KeyboardInterrupt

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exitTask = True
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        exit(0)
```

Comment: It works well! I have a doubt. Will the code start one thread every time or it creates only one thread that runs in parallel to the main while?

Comment: In a high level perspective, at a point of time, there is only one thread running in parallel to the main function, but if you look closely in the line `threading.Timer(3.0, threadTask).start()`, it basically creates a thread that executes `threadTask` after 3 sec has passed.

Comment: When the thread starts it executes `threadTask` function. At this moment, are we not starting a thread again and again or how the frame is saved if the `if` statement is only executed once?

Comment: Let me rephrase it. When the **program** starts, it executes `threadTask` function once(line 17). This creates a **thread** to run after a delay of 3s(line 10) and continues its work i.e, check for `writeToFile` variable, which is initially `False`. Then the while loop starts, which reads every frame and set `writeToFile` if the specified condition is true. This will go on for a few frames untill the previously defined thread starts executing when the 3s delay is over. If `writeToFile` is set at that time, the frame will be saved, else no.

Comment: You can probably improvise that last part by keeping in memory the last known frame which satisfied the contour conditions and save it when the 3s delay is over. This is just to make sure that if in case the particular frame being processed at the time when the thread executed, doesn't satisfy the required conditions, but the frame just before the current one did satisfy the conditions and you probably missed it. I would recommend doing this if you plan on keeping the long 3s delay. If the delay time is much less, you would be fine without this step.